# How to create an array of HTML Buttons in TypeScript and React

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I want to create an array of Buttons which will be rendered by React. The Button is a standard HTML element.

```
let buttons: HTMLButtonElement[] = []
for(let [key, value] of SomeMap) {
    buttons.push(<button onClick={...}>{value}</button>)
}
```

But this gives me

> Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLButtonElement'.   Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLButtonElement': disabled, form, formAction, formEnctype, and 300 more.

and

> Type 'HTMLButtonElement[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
> Type 'HTMLButtonElement[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactFragment'.
> The types returned by 'Symbol.iterator.next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
> Type 'IteratorResult<HTMLButtonElement, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<ReactNode, any>'.
> Type 'IteratorYieldResult' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<ReactNode, any>'.
> Type 'IteratorYieldResult' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult'.
> Type 'HTMLButtonElement' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
> Type 'HTMLButtonElement' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, props
> How woould I create an empty array that can hold buttons in React and TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with

```
let buttons: JSX.Elements[] = []
```